# form error Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Tags: 7, forms

It's pretty stright forward, im trying to display the results of my form, Im having trouble finding something that explains how to display the results outside of the  `drupal_set_message()` code, I think I am close with my current code.However I am getting this error Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

```
/** 
 * Block info 
 */ 

function zillow_block_info(){
    $blocks['zillow_block'] = array(
        'info' => t('Zillow Block'),
    );
    return $blocks;
}

function zillow_block_view($delta = ''){
    $block = array();
        switch ($delta){
    case 'zillow_block';
        $block['subject'] = t('Zillow Block');
        $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('zillow_form');
    break;
    }
    return $block;
}

/**
 * Api info 
*/

function zillow_api_info($form, &$zinfo){
    set_time_limit(3600);
    $state = $zinfo['values']['state'];
    $zillow_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
    $xml = file_get_contents('http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetRateSummary.htm?zws-id='.$zillow_id.'&state='.$state.'');
    $zinfo = simplexml_load_string($xml);

    foreach($zinfo->response as $rates){
        $zinfo .= $rates->today->rate[0];
        $zinfo .= $rates->today->rate[1];
        $zinfo .= $rates->today->rate[2];
        $zinfo .= $rates->lastWeek->rate[0];
        $zinfo .= $rates->lastWeek->rate[1];
        $zinfo .= $rates->lastWeek->rate[2];
    }

    return $zinfo;
}

/**
 * Form
 */

function zillow_form($form, &$zinfo){

    $form['description'] = array(
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#title' => t('Get your mortgage rates'),
    );
    $form['rates'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Mortgage Rates'),
        '#collapsiable' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    );

    $form['rates']['state'] = array(
        '#type' => ('select'),
        '#title' => t('Choose One'),
        '#options' => array( 
            'AK' => t('Alaska'),  
            'AZ' => t('Arizona'),
        ),
        '#required' => TRUE
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    if(isset($zinfo['values'])){
        $form['page_output'] = array(
        'markup' => 'Submitted value:'. $zinfo['values']['state']); 
    }
    return $form;
}

/**
 * Submission Output    
*/

function zillow_form_submit($form, &$zinfo){
  drupal_set_message(t('this is the info the form has submitted. states=@states, todaysrates=@todaysrates', array('@states' => $zinfo['values']['state'], '@todaysrates' => zillow_api_info($form, $zinfo))));
  $zinfo['processed']['states'] =  serialize($zinfo['values']['state']);
  $zinfo['processed']['todaysrates'] =  serialize(zillow_api_info($form, $zinfo));
}
```

Edit** My code has been modified I am now only getting this error

Comment: Your code is a mess, if you spent some time cleaning it up it would be easier to see what's going on and you might fix the problem yourself.

Comment: I didnt realize it was really a mess, I have comments above the functions that are being used... Anyhow its a little cleaner, but it is necessary to use my whole code

Comment: You should use Drupal naming conventions, it seems like `$zinfo` should be `$form_state`, you api function takes `$form` but doesn't use it. The error you get is due to an form array containing values that aren't allowed, but nothing looks wrong. (All non `#attributes` should be arrays).

Comment: If that's the case and there's nothing wrong with my code then it should work correctly, however it doesn't... Even if i do take the api function off it still does not output the results...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if(isset($zinfo['values'])){
    $form['page_output'] = array(
    'markup' => 'Submitted value:'. $zinfo['values']['state']); 
}
```

Any element of a render-array that doesn't start with a `#` symbol is itself considered a child render-array by the `drupal_render()` function.

As `drupal_render()` expects an array when your array key is `markup` (without the `#`), it tries to treat the variable as an array. Since it's a string, PHP complains that it can't use the provided variable as an array...because it isn't one :)

This should work:

```
if(isset($zinfo['values'])){
    $form['page_output'] = array(
    '#markup' => 'Submitted value:'. $zinfo['values']['state']); 
}
```

Have a look at [Render Arrays in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/930760) and the FAPI [`#markup` property](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup-attribute) for more information.

**EDIT**

There's a slightly bigger problem: in `zillow_api_info()` you're accepting the `$zinfo` parameter by reference, and then overwriting it with this call: `$zinfo = simplexml_load_string($xml);`.

That code overwrites the `$zinfo` variable in memory, so when you use it again in your submission function it will cause errors. It's also what's causing the last two lines not to work, and `$zinfo['values']` to not exist when your form is rebuilt.

The easiest solution is to change `zillow_api_info()` to look like this:

```
function zillow_api_info($form, &$form_state){
  set_time_limit(3600);
  $state = $form_state['values']['state'];
  $zillow_id = 'XXXXX';
  $xml = file_get_contents('http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetRateSummary.htm?zws-id='.$zillow_id.'&state='.$state.'');
  $zinfo2 = simplexml_load_string($xml);

  foreach($zinfo2->response as $rates){
    $zinfo2 .= $rates->today->rate[0];
    $zinfo2 .= $rates->today->rate[1];
    $zinfo2 .= $rates->today->rate[2];
    $zinfo2 .= $rates->lastWeek->rate[0];
    $zinfo2 .= $rates->lastWeek->rate[1];
    $zinfo2 .= $rates->lastWeek->rate[2];
  }

  return $zinfo2;
}
```

As an extra note, you do need `$zinfo['rebuild'] = TRUE` in your submit function too.

I'd really advise using the `$form_state` variable name throughout your code when it refers to the form state array, it'll make problems like this vanish instantly :)

Comment: Thank you for replying, I tried what you said and although that may be a problem is did not fix the error I am continuously getting. The error is on the last to lines of the code at the bottom. And even if I take those out, It still does not output the value that was select, for example if I select a state lets say california for example and I click submit, it should output california. It does that fine in drupal_set_message but doesnt do it on the actual page.

Comment: Try adding `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` into the `zillow_form_submit()` function...that will probably help. If it doesn't work let me know and I'll make a quick module with your code in it to find the problem

Comment: Yeah i had that in before I posted a edit of my code, it still gave off the same error, your welcome to try to make the module, I really appreciate it.

Comment: No probs I'll have a go now there's nothing good on the telly anyway :) Are you able to share a valid `$zillow_id` so I can get the proper data from your webservice? Don't worry if not, I'll just fudge some data

Comment: @JeremyLove I've got it working in the test module, I've edited the answer and it should help :)

Comment: Thank you I greatly appreciate it, I been scratching my head on this problem for a over a day now. THANK YOU!

Comment: You're welcome, I know how frustrating these things can be :)